# The set of σ-algebra is countable or it is the complement of countable set

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathit A$  = {{$x$}: $x \in \mathbb R$}. Show that each set $\mathsf A \in σ(\mathit A)$ is a countable set or is the complement of the countable set.

I can prove it simply using real numbers.

**My solution:**

If I take, for example, $\mathsf A$  = {$1,1.2, 3.8$}, then it is a countable set.  Can I prove in this way? If I can, how to show that it can be a complement of countable set?

Comment: No, you haven't proved anything.

Comment: Since you have to prove that each set is countable, showing that $A = \{1, 1.2, 3.8 \}$ is simply proving that the specific set $A$ is countable, but we need to prove it for _any_ set $A \in \sigma(A)$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the set $B = \{X \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) | X \text{ or } X^c \text{ is countable} \}$. $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra:

- $\mathbb{R} \in B$ because $\mathbb{R}^c = \emptyset$ is countable;
- if $X \in B$ then $X^c \in B$ (if $X$ countable $\Rightarrow$ $(X^c)^c$ is countable; if $X\in B$ not countable $\Rightarrow X^c$ countable)
- if $X_i \in B, i \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\cup_\mathbb{i \in N}X_i$ (if all $X_i$ are countable, then the union is countable; if exists an $X_j$ non countable, then $(\cup_\mathbb{i \in N}X_i)^c = \cap_\mathbb{i \in N}X_i^c \subset X_j^c$ is countable)

Then $A \subset B \Rightarrow \sigma(A) \subset B$, because $\sigma(A)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $A$.